# Варианты проверки данных с БД

Tags: php

День добрый, нашел вот такой вариант проверки на существование логина при регистрации
    # проверяем, не сущестует ли пользователя с таким именем

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."'");

    if(mysql_result($query, 0) > 0)
    {
        $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует в базе данных";
    }
```

Сам навоял вот такой вот код

```
function userChk () {
$nQ = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = '" . $_POST['name'] . "'");

if(mysql_num_rows($nQ)) {
    echo "name found";
}
```

Есть ли в них принципиальные отличия которые в будущем повлияют на корректоность работы!

И несовсем понял почему (в первом) варианте используется .mysql_real_escape_string,  в описнании указано что это функция экранирует спец. символы, зачем это нужно в данном случае? В логине могут попасться спец. симовлы которые необходимо будет экранировать??! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На счет SELECT COUNT vs SELECT name лучше почитать, например, ответы [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659977/mysql-count-vs-mysql-select-which-one-is-faster)

Где-то видел и более развернутые ответы, но суть та же.

От себя добавлю - если так же необходимо выполнять какие-либо действия (например, проверять - админ это или нет и в зависимости от этого, например, выводить форму администратора), то лучше использовать ваш вариант - если сразу добавить необходимые поля.

Т.е. не только проверили на существование, но и получили необходимую инфу. Уменьшаете кол-во запросов к БД

Answer (score 2):

Если я логином укажу строку "`'; drop table users;`", то ваш вариант сотрёт таблицу пользователей. В первом варианте посредством `mysql_real_escape_string` экранируются служебные символы вроде кавычек, которые могут повлиять на структуру SQL-запроса. Почитайте про [SQL-инъекции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно!